# Sorting array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with multiple objects such as this:

```
var test = [
 {size: "85A (UK 42A)"},
 {size: "80A (UK 40A)"},
 {size: "105F (UK 48F)"},
 {size: "95E (UK 46E)"},
 {size: "92C (UK 44C)"}
]
```

I want to order it by the size such that the order becomes as below.

```
var test = [
 {size: "80A (UK 40A)"}
 {size: "85A (UK 42A)"},
 {size: "92C (UK 44C)"}
 {size: "95E (UK 46E)"},
 {size: "105F (UK 48F)"}
]
```

I have used this but this returns me the array below:

```
function sorting(json_object, key_to_sort_by) {
 function sortByKey(a, b) {
   var x = a[key_to_sort_by];
   var y = b[key_to_sort_by];
   return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
 }

 json_object.sort(sortByKey);
}


var test = [
 {size: "105F (UK 48F)"},
 {size: "80A (UK 40A)"}
 {size: "85A (UK 42A)"},
 {size: "92C (UK 44C)"}
 {size: "95E (UK 46E)"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to sort with the character after the number as well, you could use a regular expression for getting this value, too.

```js
var test = [{ size: "105F (UK 48F)" }, { size: "80A (UK 40A)" }, { size: "85A (UK  2A)" }, { size: "92C (UK 44C)" }, { size: "80B (UK 40B)" }, { size: "80C (UK 40C)" }, { size: "95E (UK 46E)" }];

test.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getV(s) { return s.match(/^(\d+)(\w+)/); }
    var aa = getV(a.size),
        bb = getV(b.size);
    return aa[1] - bb[1] || aa[2].localeCompare(bb[2]);
});

console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For huge data sets, you could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map), because

> The `compareFunction` can be invoked multiple times per element within the array. Depending on the `compareFunction`'s nature, this may yield a high overhead. The more work a `compareFunction` does and the more elements there are to sort, the wiser it may be to consider using a map for sorting. The idea is to walk the array once to extract the actual values used for sorting into a temporary array, sort the temporary array and then walk the temporary array to achieve the right order.

```js
// the array to be sorted
var list = [{ size: "105F (UK 48F)" }, { size: "80A (UK 40A)" }, { size: "85A (UK  2A)" }, { size: "92C (UK 44C)" }, { size: "80B (UK 40B)" }, { size: "80C (UK 40C)" }, { size: "95E (UK 46E)" }];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = list.map(function(el, i) {
    var temp = el.size.match(/^(\d+)(\w+)/);
    return { index: i, number: +temp[1], string: temp[2] || '' };
});

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.number - b.number || a.string.localeCompare(b.string);
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function(el){
    return list[el.index];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Doesnt the function get called for every pair of elemnts? Doesnt that mean you're recreating `getN` on every iteration?

Comment: right, you yould use sorting with map where the map contains the values for sorting, or just spend a new property to each object, or use a hash table for the values, depending of the size of the array for sorting. for a small set, optimizing is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

By default, sort will sort strings by Unicode code point. You'd want to isolate something numerical to sort by and then turn that into a number and use that for the comparison. Something like this should work...

```js
let sizes = [
    {size: "85A (UK 42A)"},
    {size: "80A (UK 40A)"},
    {size: "105F (UK 48F)"},
    {size: "95E (UK 46E)"},
    {size: "92C (UK 44C)"},
    {size: "80B (UK 40B)"},
];

sizes.sort(function(a, b) {

    var sizeA = a.size.split(' ')[0];
    var sizeB = b.size.split(' ')[0];

    let aInt = parseInt(sizeA);
    let bInt = parseInt(sizeB);
    
    // If the same number, we can just compare the strings
    // since the numeric characters will be equal.
    if (aInt === bInt) {
       return sizeA.localeCompare(sizeB);
    }

    // If not equal, compare the numbers.
    return aInt - bInt;
});

// For snippet.
console.log(sizes);
```

Edit: Assuming that if the numeric component is the same, you'd want to sort by the letter. In this case we just compare the strings.

Comment: Assuming this might actually be more complicated than it first appears, if you want to subsequently sort by letter if the numbers are the same?

Comment: Yes If the numbers are the same I will want to sort by letter too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var test = [
 {size: "85A (UK 42A)"},
 {size: "80A (UK 40A)"},
 {size: "105F (UK 48F)"},
 {size: "95E (UK 46E)"},
 {size: "92C (UK 44C)"}
]

var sorted=test.sort(function(a, b) {
             return parseInt(a['size'].split(' ')[0])-parseInt(b['size'].split('(')[0]);
           })
console.log(sorted);
```